# Why is kubuntu adding a .directoy file to my directories?

Tags: kubuntu, dolphin, hidden-files

I was in the middle of working on a project and creating a ruby gem for it when `gem build` gave me an error saying that the `.directory` file in the project was causing issues. I never added a file like that, so I took a look using the Dolphin file explorer. It was there, and it looks like it's a text file with settings for Dolphin and for this directory, saying to show previews and hidden files.

I had never run into this before, and had been creating ruby gems earlier in the day too without any such issues. The file just keeps coming back even if I try deleting it.

What is going on??? How can I remove these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dolphine uses these `.directory files` to know how to present a directory show previews, hidden files, etc. So delete the one in the `gem directory`

You can change this behaviour by doing this:

```
go to settings and select general
```

then

```
enable "Use common properties for all folders"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just did this and `gem build` is still telling me it is there even though I can't see it there any longer.

Comment: Also, when I opened the terminal in a directory with a .directory file in it and ran `ls -a` the .directory file was not listed. Why is this? I thought `ls -a` would show everything, including hidden files.

Comment: That is quite troubling as it should not show up.

Comment: Please restart your system again check if the command still lists the `.directory` folder

Comment: I think that fixed it. Thanks! Still kind of worries me that `ls -a` didn't show them though. I thought that was kind of an end all be all type of thing that would definitely show everything every time.

Comment: these tools work with a database and since after your deletion it wasn't updated then you would still see the old records with the `directory` entry